# Cannot get data to insert into Real Time Firebase Db

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Pretty simple, here is the layout I am going for with firebase

[image]

Rules are set to be completely open as well.

Not sure if it is naming conventions I am missing or that I am using a hashmap to try to pass in a chunk of data rather than calling .setValue() twice.

```java
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegistrationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };

        mRegister = findViewById(R.id.register);
        mEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        mPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.name);

        mRadioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        mRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int selectedInstrument = mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                final RadioButton radioButton = findViewById(selectedInstrument);

                final String email = mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = mPassword.getText().toString();
                final String name = mName.getText().toString();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(RegistrationActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(RegistrationActivity.this, "Registration Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            String Uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference currentUserDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(Uid);
                            Map userInfo = new HashMap<>();
                            userInfo.put("name", name);
                            userInfo.put("instrument", radioButton.getText().toString());
                            currentUserDb.updateChildren(userInfo);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: follow and understand the firebase database documentation for a better understanding of to upload the data into the database. You are not doing it correctly.

Comment: Plase add the code where you are adding data to the database.

Comment: When you put a breakpoint on `currentUserDb.updateChildren(userInfo);` and run the app in a debugger, does it reach that breakpoint? If so, is the contents of `userInfo` what you'd expect it to be at that point? If so, if you step over `currentUserDb.updateChildren(userInfo);`, are there any relevant error messages written to logcat?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I can hit that break point with no errors. userInfo is as expected, map[0] key "name" with the value and map[1] key "instrument" with the value. I see no error messages after stepping over.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not sure what's happening in that case. I hope somebody else spots it.